# Spring, how do I set the file shown when / is hit?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

With Spring MVC 3, when a user goes to http://localhost/myspringapp/ how do I decide what page they will see? I currently get a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a mapping on a Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/") @Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping
    public String index() { /* your action */ }
```

You can also set a JSP file as `welcome-file` in your `web.xml`.